# Query including belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating a webb app, mostly to learn more rails development, for buying and selling stuff, in this case horses. A important part of the application is a "good" search engine to find what you're looking for. With the help of [railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/343-full-text-search-in-postgresql) I managed to get a text search going with this:

```
//horse.rb model
def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
        where("name @@ :q or description @@ :q", q: query)
    else
        scoped
    end
end

//horses_controller.rb
@horses = Horse.text_search(params[:query])
```

But the horses belongs_to a seller and I want to be able to search for that association as well with the same query. I did a pretty bad hack where I query the Sellers and then render their horses but that will produce duplicates.

Is there any way to do a nice query without duplicates?

---

I ended up doing this:

```
//horses_controller.rb
@horses = Horse.text_search(params[:query])
@horses += Horse.seller_search(params[:query])
@horses = @horses.uniq

//horse.rb (model)
def self.text_search(query)
    if query.present?
        where("name @@ :q or description @@ :q", q: query)
    else
        scoped
    end
end

def self.seller_search(query)
    if query.present?
        joins(:seller).where("sellers.name @@ :q", q: query)
    else
        nil
    end
end
```

If there's a more elegant way to do this please let me know.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `WHERE EXISTS` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you already look at the "joins" method in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html ?

If you want to prevent duplicates, also look at the "uniq" method in the same doc

Comment: Thanks, I read up on both joins and uniq. I now do multiple querys: one for the horses to see if any of them matches the query. Then I do one for the sellers with joins to return the horses for the sellers. To top it off I add them together and calls uniq to remove duplicates.